# Force IDE to use Webpack resolve aliases for Typescript modules

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webpack

I do love using Typescript in my projects.

And I also have **Resolve Aliases** in my **webpack config**. The thing is that my IDE (let's say **Intellij Idea**). And my IDE is happy to autocomplete all aliases stuff in for me in **Javascript** modules.

In fact i want the same for **Typescript** modules, but my IDE pushes me to fill out **tsconfig.json -> compilerOprions -> paths**, which I don't want to do.

Can I somehow teach my IDE to use webpack's aliases in typescript modules?

Comment: The Typescript compiler provides the language services, and the language service knows how to use `tsconfig.json` I don't expect there is a way to do this

Comment: Why don't you want to add them in your tsconfig? You just have to add them there and it will work.

Comment: Okay, some details is here: 
The thing is that I generate aliases dynamically, while I form webpack config. and it works perfect, all imports work correctly for JS and TS as well. because I add { resolve: { alias: myAliases } } for webpack and { CompilerOptions: { paths: myAliases } } for my ts-loader
but my IDE does not know about it, so'm looking for the way how to provide aliases for IDE.
My idea was to dump webpack-like aliases into cached file, and then IDE started to complete my code, but it only works for Javascript. Can't find solution for Typescript files

Answer (score 1):

webpack aliases are only supported for JavaScript. Current TypeScript implementation uses only the TypeScript resolution logic because we need to keep integration with the TypeScript service. You can configure the same mappings in `tsconfig.json` file using `"paths": {}`. 
Please vote for [WEB-29207](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29207) to be notified on any progress with it.